Running Java code in VS Code is not working unless I write the same lines over and over again
I wrote code for a linked list, adding a node. I use VS Code, but when I am want to run the code it's not working. This is my code:
package Linked_List;

import java.util.*;

public class Insertion{

    class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
    
        Node(int data){
            this.data=data;
            this.next=null;         
        }
    }  

    Node head=null;  

    public void creation(){
        int data,n;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.println("enter data");
            data=sc.nextInt();
            Node newnode=new Node(data);
            if(head==null){
                head=newnode;   
            }
            else{
                newnode.next=head;
                head=newnode;
            }
            System.out.println("do you want to continue press y for yes");
            n=sc.next().charAt(0);

        }while(n=='y'|| n=='Y');
        
    }
    public  void traverse(){
        Node temp=head;
        if(head==null){
            System.out.println("linled list dont exist");
        }
        else{
            while(temp!=null){
                System.out.println(temp.data);
                temp=temp.next;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Insertion list = new Insertion();
        list.creation();
        list.traverse();
        
    }
}

Here the code is right but the problem is I have to write it over and over again:
1-javac Linked_List/Insertion.java
2-java Linked_List/Insertion

This file (Insertion.java) is in a folder named Linked_List
I don't want to write these two lines over and over again; when I click on run code it want it just to run. What can I do for that to happen?

Do not tag this as dsa.  The dsa tag is for Digital Signature Algorithm.

You can create a script (.bat or .sh) to run couple commands.
